# Write a PDF to buffer in MuPDF C API

Tags: c, mupdf

I try to write the PDF document created by MuPDF to a buffer

```
#include <mupdf/fitz.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    fz_matrix ctm;
    ctm = fz_scale(1, 1);
    ctm = fz_pre_rotate(ctm, 0);
    fz_context *ctx = fz_new_context(NULL, NULL, FZ_STORE_UNLIMITED);
    fz_buffer *output = fz_new_buffer(ctx, 0);
    fz_document_writer *wri = fz_new_document_writer_with_buffer(ctx, output, "pdf", NULL);

    fz_rect mediabox = {0, 0, 600, 800};

    fz_device *begin = fz_begin_page(ctx, wri, mediabox);

    fz_rect where = {50, 50, 250, 250};
    const char *html = "<h1>Hello World!</h1>";
    fz_buffer *buf = fz_new_buffer(ctx, 0);
    fz_append_string(ctx, buf, html);
    fz_story *story = fz_new_story(ctx, buf, NULL, 12.0, NULL);
    int out = fz_place_story(ctx, story, where, &where);
    fz_draw_story(ctx, story, begin, ctm);

    fz_end_page(ctx, wri);

    fz_close_document_writer(ctx, wri);
}
```

but I hit SIGSEGV at `fz_close_document_writer`. As checked by `gdb`, the problem is at appending the PDF data using `fz_append_data`.

Comment: Maybe check the return values of all those function calls